# In Java what exactly does File.canExecute() do?

Tags: java, file, permissions, io

I have created a plain file which does not have execute permission but when I create a Java File object using this file's path/name and then call File.canExecute() I get true as the result, whereas I would expect this method call to return false.  Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Solaris:

```
$ touch /tmp/nonexecutable
$ ls -l /tmp/nonexecutable
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           0 May 21 07:48 /tmp/nonexecutable
```

Java:

```
String pathName = "/tmp/nonexecutable";
File myFile = new File(pathName);
if (!myFile.canExecute())
{
    String errorMessage = "The file is not executable.";
    log.error(errorMessage);
    throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

--James

Answer (score 5):

Nothing to do with Java - you're running as root, and root is allowed everything, not matter what the permissions say.

Comment: Nothing in his post indicates that he's running as root.

Comment: The file is owned by root.root and it's just been created, indicating the OP is running as root

Comment: I just wrote some code that creates a new file, asserts canExecute is false, then does a chmod exec call, turning the execute bit on. Now canExecute returns true. Is that because I'm doing all of this as me and not root?

Answer (score 3):

Though I'm not an expert, and this will not answer your question properly, I'd like to add that this behavior is not specific to Java. From the find (GNU findutils) 4.4.0 manpage on my Ubuntu 8.10 install, regarding the `-executable` flag:

> Matches  files  which  are 
>   executable and directories which are 
>   searchable (in a file name resolution
>   sense).  This  takes  into  account 
>   access  control  lists  and other
>   permissions artefacts  which the `-perm`
>   test  ignores.   This  test  makes 
>   use  of  the  [`access(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) system call,
>   and so can be fooled by NFS servers
>   which  do UID mapping (or
>   root-squashing), since many systems
>   implement  `access(2)`  in  the client’s
>   kernel and so cannot make use of the 
>   UID mapping information held on the
>   server.  Because  this  test  is 
>   based only on the result of the
>   `access(2)` system call, **there  is no
>   guarantee that a file for which  this 
>   test  succeeds  can  actually be
>   executed**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bug which was opened on JDK on this:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=8b833c54cb93d6c9cf416667dc02?bug_id=6379654

The conclusion is that File.canExecute() simply translates into a native posix call to access(path, X_OK). Linux returns false and solaris returns true for that call when run as root.

Finally, the bug was closed as Wont Fix! :)