# Java File.canExecute() always return false on Red Hat 6.5

Tags: java, unix, redhat, java-io

I have a simple program to create file named test12345678.bin under java temp directroy(/tmp) and perform the chmod using File.setExecutable. After than, the program will did a verification to make sure the generated file is always executable by using File.canExecute.

I have run this simple program on different environment, but only this environment installed with Red Hat 6.5 is giving me the problem in which the canExecute is always return "false". I also did a test by manually execute the generated file and its executable and the permission for the file are -rwxr-xr-x; 
Java version that am using on all my testing env are the same; 1.6.0_38.

Before this, the Red Hat 6.5 is tested under root/superuser. After gone through some discussion stated below, I re-configured the user back to normal user, but still no luck on this. Any 1 have idea about this canExecute on Red hat 6.5 ?

[In Java what exactly does File.canExecute() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891857/in-java-what-exactly-does-file-canexecute-do)

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=8b833c54cb93d6c9cf416667dc02?bug_id=6379654

http://linux.die.net/man/2/access

```
        File tmp = File.createTempFile( "test", ".bin" );            
        FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream( tmp );
        try {
            o.write( 255 );
            o.flush();
            o.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( "[IO_EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage() );                
        } finally {
            o.close();
        }

        tmp.setExecutable( true, true );

        String path = tmp.getAbsolutePath();
        File test= new File( path );
        boolean ret = test.canExecute();
        System.out.println("---> tmp file created " + path + "| executable? " + ret);
```

Comment: Did you try any other existing file on the same location with canExecute?

Comment: The bug report you cite is closed as "won't fix", and clearly ascribes the behaviour to the platform itself, not to Java. It is therefore difficult to see why you're even asking.

Comment: UVM: I never try on other existing file on the same location, probably u got the point, will try that out later.
EJP: But if i come closer to the bug reported, it is something related to the root/super user. Correct me if i am wrong. Perhaps it happen regardless of any user group.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question with the first link:

[In Java what exactly does File.canExecute() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891857/in-java-what-exactly-does-file-canexecute-do)

> The conclusion is that File.canExecute() simply translates into a
>   native posix call to [access(path, X_OK)](http://www.manpages.info/linux/access.2.html).

SUGGESTION:

If you simply want to check the file permission bits, use [FilePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html) instead.

Comment: At first i was thinking that is just because when using root/superuser? we have changed the user back to normal user, but still have the same issue. Other environment are working fine.

Comment: Actually, the problem with root user is that it can return "executable == true" even if the "x" bit isn't set.  The exact opposite of the problem you're experiencing.  Q: What are you trying to accomplish with "File.canExecute()"?  If you're looking for the "x", then "canExecute()" is probably a poor choice.  "FilePermission" would work better.  IMHO...

Comment: Hi, Actually am looking for the "x" and trying not to change the program, which remain File.canExecute(). Just wondering why this environment behave differently with other environment that i tested.